# Поиск одинаковых слов в c#?

Tags: c#, .net, нейронные-сети

нужно написать программу на с# которая сможет среди разных слов определять, что слово одно и тоже, если, к примеру в словах есть ошибки
"молоко"-"малоко"
"фентези"="фэнтези"
Нужно чтобы программа определила, что имелось ввиду одно и тоже слово

Нужно ли для этого использовать нейросеть? Есть ли примеры реализаций похожих вещей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо, вам нужно просто [растояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Levenshtein_Distance
{
    public static class StringDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the distance between two strings.
        /// </summary>
        public static int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }

            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }

            // Step 2
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            {
            }

            // Step 3
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                //Step 4
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(StringDistance.LevenshteinDistance("Лук", "Люк"));
            Console.WriteLine(StringDistance.LevenshteinDistance("Трактор", "Самолет"));
            Console.WriteLine(StringDistance.LevenshteinDistance("Кремень", "Картон"));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

В вашем примере на "молоко" vs "малоко" расстояние Левенштейна всего лишь 1.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку и за пример, как раз то, что нужно